# Merging conflicts of reindex api in elasticsearch

Tags: database, elasticsearch, nosql, spring-data-elasticsearch, reindex

I need to merge conflicts in reindex api. But it just completele removes the dest old document and replaces it with what I provide in source instead of just changing the fields that source has and not touching other destination fields
I have two indexes in elasticsearch named i1 and i2
i2 was reindexed from i1 a long time ago and shares ids with i1
i2 has new values for most of its fields and old values in i1 aren't usefull for me
But i1 has received a lot of new fields with new values recently and I want to add them to v2
I used reindex api on a test index with source fields limited to only the new fields from v1 (with _source: []). But saw that reindexing removed every other field from destination and only the fields that I specified to be moved to destination remain.
Is there a way to tell reindex api to only add new fields in case of id similarity and not remove the destination fields that don't don't exist in the source?

Tried setting version type to external but it just checks which one is newer before completely replacing or doing nothing.

document example in i1:
{
"id": "1",
"f1": "vOld",
"f2": "v"
}

document example in i2:
{
"id": "1",
"f1": "vNew"
}

result I want in i2 after reindexing:
{
"id": "1",
"f1": "vNew",
"f2": "v"
}

my query:
POST _reindex
{
"source": {
"index": "i1"
},
"dest": {
"index": "i2",
"_source": ["f2"]
}
}
}

Comment: please share the reindex request you are making and some document examples

Comment: I edited my post and added examples at the end @warkolm